# how to add multiple linked tools in visual studio c++ form dynamical y

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-studio-2013, qt5

This is my first time working in visual studio ,previously i made a gui on ubuntu with qt but now have create the same in visual studio.

I am unable to under stand how to make a new class consist of two editbox and a button grouped together in a groupbox such that i can add the whole unit in my c++ form dynamicaly.

Let me explain with my current QT code:

In by QT version i created a class cal_widget:

cal_widget.h

```
///THIS CLASS IS USED AS A CALIBRATION WIDGET FOR EACH ENTRY IN CALIBRATION VECTOR AN OBJCT OF THIS CLASS IS MADE
/// TO GET PIXEL MEASUREMENT OF A PARTICULAR CALIBRATION FEATURE FROM ITS PHYSICAL MEASUREMENT
#ifndef CAL_WIDGET_H
#define CAL_WIDGET_H
#include <QWidget>
#include<QGroupBox>
#include<QGridLayout>
#include<QPushButton>
#include<QLineEdit>
#include<QLabel>
class cal_widget : public QGroupBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit cal_widget(const QString& feature, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    QGridLayout* layout;
    QPushButton* btn;
    QLineEdit* ln1;
    QLineEdit* ln2;
    int cal_index;

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // CAL_WIDGET_H
```

cal_widget.cpp

```
#include "cal_widget.h"

cal_widget::cal_widget(const QString& feature, QWidget *parent) : QGroupBox(parent)
{

    /////ADD what'sthis and placeholder
    this->setTitle(feature);
    layout = new QGridLayout();
    btn= new QPushButton("SELECT ROI");
    ln1 = new QLineEdit();
    ln2 = new QLineEdit();
    ln2->setReadOnly(true);
    ln1->setPlaceholderText("Enter value in mm");
    layout->addWidget(ln1,0,0);
    layout->addWidget(ln2,0,1);
    layout->addWidget(btn,1,0,1,2);
    this->setLayout(layout);
}
```

and add these using this in my main code:

```
  /////ADDING EVERY CALIBRATION TYPE ELEMENT ACCORDING TO CAMERA ID
    for(int i=0;i<cal.size();i++)
    {
        cal_wid.push_back(new cal_widget(cal[i]->name,this));
        cal_wid[cal_wid.size()-1]->cal_index=i;
        connect(cal_wid[cal_wid.size()-1]->btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),cal_map,SLOT(map()));
        cal_map->setMapping(cal_wid[cal_wid.size()-1]->btn,i);
        if(cal[i]->cam_id==1)
            vbox->addWidget(cal_wid[cal_wid.size()-1]);
        else if(cal[i]->cam_id==2)
            vbox2->addWidget(cal_wid[cal_wid.size()-1]);
        else if(cal[i]->cam_id==3)
            vbox3->addWidget(cal_wid[cal_wid.size()-1]);
        else if(cal[i]->cam_id==2)
            vbox3->addWidget(cal_wid[cal_wid.size()-1]);

     }
```

so that it gives me a look like this:[image: vbox before loading calibration parameters]
[image: After Loading calibration Parameter]

now I want to do same in the form(CLR) i have created in visual studio can some one tell me how to so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1, Add a new item by right clicking your application, then select the UserControl:

2, Drag the controls what you want to the user control interface:

3, Build the application and you will find there is a user control appearing in the toolbox, drag it to the form to do your purpose.